# Exception Handler error code in Thread Local Storage

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Exception Handler error when using *wprintf* in Thread Local Storage but I don't have problem in Main EntryPoint, I noticed the problem occurs when *Runtime Library* set to */MT* or */MTd*, Please see the screenshot, What's the solution?
IDE: Visual Studio 2015, OS: Win10 64bit

[Sample Project](https://hostr.co/ZSIedMmehLtb)

```
void NTAPI TLSCallbacks(PVOID DllHandle, DWORD dwReason, PVOID Reserved) 
{wprintf(L"%s procedure called with DllHandle=0x%p, Reason=%d.\n", TEXT(__FUNCTION__), DllHandle, dwReason); }

// end declaration

//linker spec
#ifdef _M_IX86
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__xl_b")
#else
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_xl_b")
#endif
#ifdef _M_X64
#pragma const_seg (".CRT$XLB") const
#else
#pragma data_seg (".CRT$XLB")
#endif //end linker 

//tls import 
EXTERN_C PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _xl_b = TLSCallbacks;
#pragma data_seg ()
#pragma const_seg () //end
```

[image]

[image: CallStack]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I update question, Please see the screenshot.

Comment: This may sound tough, but you need to provide a **reproducible, simple as possible** example that is complete, so that readers can try it.

Comment: When the error dialog appears, click on the Break button, this will break into the debugger and then look at the call stack.

Comment: I upload a sample.

Comment: It doesn't compile here with VS2015. I get : `Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  TLS_Test c:\users\...\tls\tls_test\tls_test.cpp 48`.

Comment: Platform set to x86.

Comment: It doesn't crash here. What does your call stack look like ?

Comment: I noticed the problem occurs when `Runtime Library` set to /MT or /MTd.